# Tooltwist Designer Sync Error

Tags: tooltwist

I am geeting below error

ERROR GitRepository - Error in getSyncList(): exit-status=1
stderr=/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- xmlsimple (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
    from /home/widgetti/server/extension-projects/ttWbd/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb:5

in one of our designer when doing a sync, what would be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused because a Ruby gem named xml-simple has not been installed. On a Linux machine, the following Ruby installation steps are required for the Designer to work.

```
yum install ruby  
yum install rubygems 
gem update  
gem update --system   
gem install xml-simple
gem install mail
```